# What is meant by 'a confusion' in this text?

Tags: semantics

Alice's Adventures in Wonderland was published in 1865, three years after Lewis Carroll and the Reverend Robinson Duckworth, on 4 July,[6] rowed up the Isis river in a boat with three young girls—a day known as the "golden afternoon,"[7] prefaced in the novel as a poem. The poem might be a confusion or even another Alice-tale, for it turns out that particular day was cool, cloudy and rainy.

Comment: An instance of confusion.

Comment: Carroll is assumed to have confused that afternoon with another one which _was_ fine.